# Сравнение двух таблиц в Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Как можно сравнить две таблицы(вторая таблица с дампа) и вывести строки, которых нет в первой(которые есть во второй) с помощью SELECT

Comment: есть уникальные идентификаторы у строк типа id? какие поля там?

Comment: id, human_id - вот эти поля

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно сделать `JOIN` обеих таблиц по полю `id`, а затем выбрать только те записи, которых нет в первой таблице. Например так:

```
SELECT d.* FROM dump_data d
    LEFT OUTER JOIN real_data r ON r.id = d.id
    WHERE r.id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

Я бы посоветовал воспользоваться инструментами типа `dbForge Studio`, которые умеют делать скрипты миграции и подобные вещи. Даже в бесплатной версии. Если вы конечно не пишите велосипед.

Answer (score 2):

Я не очень понял, где какие поля `id`, где `human_id`, но попробуйте так:

```
select *
from table2
where id not in (select id
                 from table1)
```